# How to override standard module class in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Tell me please how can i override the standart class **ModArticlesCategoryHelper**, located in **/modules/mod_articles_category/** ?
I want customize this class, but i don't want modify a joomla core.

Answer (score 0):

go to the module and click on the Advanced tab. Module Class Suffix - put some class here, make sure you put space before the class name. Like this " mycustomclass"

Then you can style anything withing that ul as you wish, for example:

ul.mycustomclass li a.ModArticlesCategoryHelper {your custom css}